# Удаления записей которым больше двух дней

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Ребята, такой вопросик, есть запись в табличке со временем, ну, например: `2006-02-12 11:50:51`. Как сделать, чтоб все записи, которым больше чем два дня удалялись? Какой нужно сформулировать запрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут главное правильно сформулировать вопрос,а не запрос. :)

```
delete from 'tname' where dtame<='2 дня'
```

Советую использовать поле INT() и там хранить timestamp вместо datetime поля, с ним и работать проще.

Comment: кнопочка под ответом есть "принять" или +1 поставить :) ну как обычно все делают хорошие люди ;)

Comment: согласен, нужно сформулировать вопрос правильно. необходимо чтобы они сами удалялись или запрос нужен?)